# Direction in ubuntu

Tags: python, ubuntu

Trying to run bot in server. Ubuntu 20.1

Line in code(Python3)

```
...
for elem in items['stats']:
        f = open(r"\root\bot_python\list.txt", "r+")
...
```

Traceback

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "bot_last_final_18_01_2021.py", line 57, in <module>
    f = open(r"\root\bot_python\list.txt", "r+")
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '\\root\\bot_python\\list.txt'
```

How correctly write directoty?

Comment: You are opening the file in read (`r+`) mode and the file doesn't exists so you get the `FileNotFound` error as expected. To create a new file and write contents to it, you need to open it in write mode.

Comment: No, he is already on server. Already check it.

Comment: bot_last_final_18_01_2021.py  list.txt

Comment: but you are trying to open this file `\root\bot_python\list.txt` in read mode? Does `list.txt` exist in the `\root\bot_python\` directory?

Comment: i think problem in wrong syntax

Comment: Yes, he is in directory

Comment: There is no syntax error. The error is clearly mentioned: `FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:`

Comment: At windows work correctly...

Answer (score 0):

Directory paths in Linux use forward slash, so try:

```python
for elem in items['stats']:
    f = open("/root/bot_python/list.txt", "r+")
```

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "bot_last_final_18_01_2021.py", line 57, in <module>
    f = open("\root\bot_python\list.txt", "r+")
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '\root\x08ot_python\\list.txt'

Comment: If this is the solution and works for you it would be nice if you could mark it as accepted answer :)

Comment: Can't accept. Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score.

Answer (score 0):

On linux you use "/" instead of "\". So the file location would be /root/bot_python/list.txt.
If that doesn't work then try without the .txt at the end. That should be it